# How do I run time stamps across multiple years and the 12 calendar months in multiple files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to create a directory that would contain the following files:

test1 test2 test3 … test4X ; where X is any number less than 20

I'm trying to update the time stamps (date/time) of the files using the `touch` command and making the time stamps run across multiple years and the 12 calendar months.

Example: `test1` will be Jan 2011; `test2` will be Feb 2014; etc.

Below is my script, but I'm unable to randomize the time stamps across multiple years and 12 calendar months.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
touch -d 2011-01-01 file{1..10}
ls -lt

Output:
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file10
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file4
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file5
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file6
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file7
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file8
-rw-r--r-- 1 Domain Users  0 Jan  1  2011 file9
```

Comment: `for month in {0..11}; do ...; done`

Comment: or `for i in {2007..2016}; do touch -d "${i}-01-01" file_$((i-2006)); done` or with a random month `for i in {2007..2016}; do touch -d "${i}-$((RANDOM % 12 + 1))-01" file_$((i-2006)); done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where it appears you are running into problems is in using a *sequence expression* to create `file{1..10}`. While that is fine, you cannot then use another *sequence expression* to manipulate the *date string* for `touch` without creating multiple variants of the date for each filename.

This is where a loop (or simply using `RANDOM`, or both) can be used to manipulate the date string to give you date-stamps over multiple years and months.

For example, to create `file_1 -- file_10` with years from `2007` through `2016` and a random month (`Jan. - Dec.`), you could do something similar to what I posted in the comment, e.g.

```
for i in {2007..2016}; do   ## for years 2007 - 2016
    ## create a file with a random month
    touch -d "${i}-$((RANDOM % 12 + 1))-01" file_$((i-2006))
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Mar  1  2007 file_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec  1  2008 file_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Oct  1  2009 file_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Mar  1  2010 file_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Jan  1  2011 file_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Aug  1  2012 file_6
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Mar  1  2013 file_7
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Mar  1  2014 file_8
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Jul  1  2015 file_9
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Dec  1  2016 file_10
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @David.thank you..what about when 100 files needs to be created and timestamps just between 2006-2017? any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: I would do `year=2006; for i in {1..100}; do if (( i % 10 == 0 )); then ((year++)); fi; touch -d "${year}-$((RANDOM % 12 + 1))-01" file_$i; done` It just adds a variable `year` and increments `year` by 1 every 10 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your complete requirement but if you want to have a start year's value to your desired end year value(till where you want to have the file's modification time), same thing with months also, then following may help you in same.

```
awk -v var=19 -v start_year="2011" -v end_year="2015" -v start_month="1" -v end_month="12" '
BEGIN{
  while((4 * var)>val){
     print "touch -d " start_year"-"start_month"-1 file"++val;
     if(start_year==end_year){
       start_year="2011"
}
  if(start_month==end_month){
     start_month="1"
}
  start_year++;
  start_month++
}
}'
```

Above code will print the commands only eg--> `touch -d 2013-1-1 file75`, so print them and once you are happy with results then use `| sh` at the last of the command which will execute these `touch` commands then.